# How to identify network computers when using doParallel

Tags: r, windows, cluster-computing, doparallel

I am trying to use `doParallel` on multiple windows PC (on network). I was told to use the following program

```
nodes <- c(rep("localhost",15),rep("node001",16))
cl <- makeCluster(nodes)
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

while I know "localhost" is the default identifier for my primary PC, but "node001" is something I don't understand. how can I identify my other computers on the network? I tried the IP address but they won't connect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is the "ssh" command installed on your local machine, and is there an "sshd" running on "localhost" and "node001"? Those are the biggest issues when trying to use the parallel package on multiple Windows machines. You may have a bit of system administration work to do before you'll get your program to work.

The first argument to `makeCluster` should be either a number or a character vector containing either host names or IP addresses. If a character vector is used, the values will be used to construct the "ssh" commands used to launch the cluster workers. If you specify a bad hostname, you might get an error message and then `makeCluster` will hang, as in:

```
> library(parallel)
> nodes = c("localhost", "node001")
> makeCluster(nodes)
ssh: Could not resolve hostname node001: Name or service not known
^C
>
```

Note that you can't really depend on seeing the error message because it depends on your R environment.

I suggest verifying that you can resolve "node001" using the R `nsl` function:

```
> nsl("node001")
NULL
Warning message:
In nsl("node001") : nsl() was unable to resolve host 'node001'
```

If this fails, then you just need to determine the right hostname or IP address. If it succeeds, then you need to keep looking for the real cause of the problem, and unfortunately there are many reasons why `makeCluster` may hang.

Comment: thanks! I am not sure if nsl works on Windows machines but i wasn't able to find a function like that. I tried directly using an ip address in makeCluster() but it didn't seem to work, eg

makeCluster("10.7.114.250")

Comment: @JD002 Does `system("nslookup localhost")` work on Windows?